# Tags derivatives, integral, limit only for computation questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

**EDIT:** This question is now obsolete - for the detailed explanation see below.

---

One of the answers [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3268/) was suggesting that [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) should be renamed to [derivatives-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives-computation) and that tag-wiki should reflect that this tag is intended ONLY for questions about computation of derivatives.
This answer has (at this moment) 7 upvotes and no downvotes - which IMO can be considered as a consensus.

In comments to that answer it was also explained that moderators have the possibility to rename tags.

I think that if we did with [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives), it would be logical to treat tags [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits) and [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) in the same way; i.e using [limit-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit-computation), [integral-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-computation) and editing tag-wikis and tag-excerpts appropriately.

As this would influence large number questions (more than 1k at this moment), this should be definitely discusses before some action is taken.

> To sum up briefly the questions I am asking:
>
> 1. Whether there is consensus that this (or something similar) should be done.
> 2. If we agree that this should be done, what would be the best way to proceed.

You can show your opinion on the first question simply by upvoting/downvoting the question. (And perhaps posting comments or answers explaining why not, if you disagree.) Proposals how to proceed - if there is agreement that we should do this at all - should be posted as answers, so that they can be up/downvoted too and we find out what is the consensus in math.SE community.

---

It is also important to mention that the current usage of these tags does not comply the above rules completely. (Despite the fact that tag-wikis and tag-excerpts explicitly say that they are indented on the questions about computation of derivatives/limits/indefinite integrals.) We have some questions concerning definition, generalization, notation, properties, theorems related to limits/derivatives/integrals under these tags. I'm giving a sample bellow; as it was quite easy to find these few examples very quickly, I guess there are plenty of similar questions.

Limits:

- [Properties of generalized limits aka nets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96434/properties-of-generalized-limits-aka-nets)
- [Wrong Definition of a Limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73811/wrong-definition-of-a-limit)
- [Why is this limit said to equal some value rather than approach that value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96420/why-is-this-limit-said-to-equal-some-value-rather-than-approach-that-value)

Derivatives:

- [Differentiating an Inner Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96265/differentiating-an-inner-product)
- [Implicit Differentiation Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94570/implicit-differentiation-proof)
- [Proof of Product Rule for Derivatives using Proof by Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90526/proof-of-product-rule-for-derivatives-using-proof-by-induction)

Integrals:

- [Why are gauge integrals not more popular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28246/why-are-gauge-integrals-not-more-popular)
- [Looking for an accessible explanation of Henstock–Kurzweil (gauge) integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54953/looking-for-an-accessible-explanation-of-henstockkurzweil-gauge-integral)
- [Questions about Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/questions-about-fubinis-theorem)

---

**EDIT:** In the meantime the tags [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) and [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) [have been synonymized](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9684/tags-integral-and-integration). Similarly, [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) and [differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differentiation) are synonyms now. So this question kind of becomes obsolete.

If it is still worth discussing, whether this should be done for the [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits) tag, it would be better to make a new question on meta about this. (I think that asking a new question is cleaner as editing this old question, explaining what have changed.)

However, if we want to handle these three tag in a consistent way, I am not sure whether we should insist that the tag [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits) should be only used for questions on computations of limits. Since I do not have strong opinion on this either way, I do not plan posting a new question about this issue. (I only wanted to edit the old post, so that is clear that this question is already obsolete - just in case someone stumbles on it by accident.)

Comment: I've put the current tag-wikis and tag-excerpts to pastebin http://pastebin.com/Czu3epL5 (So that they are not lost in case the tag names are changed.)

Answer (score 1):

If we decide to use [limit-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit-computation), [integral-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-computation) and [derivatives-computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives-computation); the best way to proceed would in my opinion be:

- Rename current tags to these names (this can be done by moderators) and edit tag-wikis and tag-excerpts where necessary.
- Create [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit), [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral) and [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) by adding a few old questions (so that the tags are not deleted). When some of old questions, which are not tagged appropriately according these new rules, are bumped, they can be retagged. (Hopefully, if we add two sets of tags; one with -computation suffix and one without, there won't be not too many new questions tagged incorrectly.)